# Asynchronous task execution using Tornado web framework

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, event-handling, tornado, future

I'm familiar with event-driven programming but I have encountered this problem and I have terminated possible solutions. I read the documentation of Tornado, I tried with:

1. Futures
2. gen.coroutine
3. asynchronous
4. add_timeout

but I was not able to solve the following problem:

- I have a websocket server that just listen for new messages
  and based on the message type it calls a specific function

  class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

  ```
  ...

  def on_message(self, message):
      if message['type'] is X:
          self.write(functionA(message['data']))
      elif message['type'] is Y:
          self.write(functionB(message['data']))
  ...
  ```

The problem comes when one computationally expensive function is execute, let say functionA, it can take up to 5 minutes to terminate

```
def functionA(message):
    params = extract_params(message)
    cmd = "computationally_expensive_tool"
    out = check_output(cmd, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, cwd=working_dir)
    ...
    return json.dumps({
                        "error": False,
                        "message": "computationally_expensive_tool_execution_terminated",
                        "type": X
                    })
```

My question is how can I execute that function in an asynchronous way so that I can still handle other messages and the result of functionA when it will be ready?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your functions look like?

Comment: Hi @notorious.no , thank you for your interest.  I added some details about the functionA and the objective that I want to achieve. So functionA call this tool and when it finish I want to be able to notify this to the client by sending him a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `functionA` is a blocking function that cannot be made asynchronous, you probably want to run it in a thread pool:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

@gen.coroutine
def on_message(self, message):
    if message['type'] is X:
        yield executor.submit(functionA, message['data'])
    elif message['type'] is Y:
        functionB(message['data'])
```

This will block this websocket until `functionA` finishes, but allow other connections to continue working. If you need to continue processing other kinds of messages from the *same* connection while `functionA` runs, you need a more complicated arrangement, possibly involving a `tornado.queues.Queue`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ben! Yes, I need to serve the same client even if functionA is still running. Is there a way to execute functionA asynchronously and attach a callback to it? so that I can do something like functionA_hadler(resultA): #do something (like reply back when the result is ready)

Comment: Yes, you can do something like `IOLoop.current().add_future(executor.submit(functionA, message['data']), callback)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works. this is definitely a solution to my problem.